# Populating related form fields with AJAX or COLDFUSION

Tags: ajax, coldfusion

I have a form field that I dynamically populate with a data list from a coldfusion query:

```
 <input size="50" name="customer_name" id="customer_name" 
       tabindex="0" onblur="checkFilled()" type="text">
 <datalist id=customers >
     <cfloop query="past_customers">
         <option>#past_customers.company_name#
     </cfloop>
 </datalist> 
 </cfoutput>
```

I will then populate a second form field based on that selection:

```
<cftextarea name="customer_address" 
    cols="50" rows="5" 
    id="customer_address" 
    tabindex="0" 
    bind="cfc:cfcs.addressdata.getAddressDetail({customer_name})" 
    bindattribute="value" 
    bindonload="true"></cftextarea>
```

Here is my CFC code:

```
<cffunction name="getAddressDetail" access="remote" returnType="string">
    <cfargument name="customer_name" type="any" required="true">

    <!--- localize function variables --->
    <cfset var dataDetail = "">

    <cfquery name="dataDetail" datasource="#datasource#">
        SELECT company_address
        FROM   closed_tickets
        WHERE company_name = <cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.customer_name#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
    </cfquery>

    <cfreturn dataDetail.company_address>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="getEmailAddressDetail" access="remote" returnType="string">
    <cfargument name="customer_name" type="any" required="true">

    <!--- localize function variables --->
    <cfset var dataDetail = "">

    <cfquery name="dataDetail" datasource="#datasource#">
        SELECT email
        FROM   closed_tickets
        WHERE company_name = <cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.customer_name#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
    </cfquery>

    <cfreturn dataDetail.email>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="getPhoneDetail" access="remote" returnType="string">
    <cfargument name="customer_name" type="any" required="true">

    <!--- localize function variables --->
    <cfset var dataDetail = "">

    <cfquery name="dataDetail" datasource="#datasource#">
        SELECT phone
        FROM   closed_tickets
        WHERE company_name = <cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.customer_name#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
    </cfquery>

    <cfreturn dataDetail.phone>
</cffunction>
```

That works as designed, however I would like to try and populate my initial input field using AJAX instead. HEre is the code I am using for that:

```
<!---Autocomplete for Quick view text box --->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
         $( "##customer_name" ).autocomplete({
                source: "cfcs/past_customers.cfc?method=lookupCustomers&returnformat=json",
                minLength: 1,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    $('##customer_name').val(ui.item.value);
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

And the new CFC:

```
<cffunction name="lookupCustomers" access="remote" output="no" hint="I return a list of customers" returnformat="JSON">
    <cfargument name="term" required="false" default="" />

    <!--- Define variables --->
    <cfset var returnArray =ArrayNew(1)>

    <!--- Do search --->
    <cfquery name="data" datasource="#datasource#">
        select distinct company_name
        From  closed_tickets
        where ticket_type = "billable" 
        AND   company_name LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#arguments.term#%" />
        order by company_name
    </cfquery>

    <!--- Build result array --->
    <cfloop query="data">
        <cfset titleStruct = structNew() />
        <cfset titleStruct['value'] = company_name />
        <cfset titleStruct['label'] = company_name />

        <cfset arrayAppend(returnArray,titleStruct) />    
    </cfloop>

    <!--- And return it --->
    <cfreturn returnArray />
</cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

I can get my initial input box to show the list, however the related input fields don't populate with the data when using the AJAX results. Everything will populate correctly when using the coldfusion LIST code. I've kept all field names the same.

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: What version of ColdFusion are you using?

Comment: I am running 9.0.0.251028

Comment: And are you getting a response back from the CFC for your autocomplete? You just can't see it in the input field?

Comment: I am getting a response and I can see the list of data that my AJAX code is fetching. However, once I select an item from the AJAX generated list in my first input box, my related form fields do not populate with data. However, if I choose an item from my non-AJAX fetched list (datalist), the related form fields will populate. I though that the related form fields wouldn't care how the content of the first form field is provided, it just uses the value of the first form field as it's argument, no matter how it was generated. No?

Comment: I do not have time to delve into this. However, it looks like you are trying to combine events from two different libraries, which may not necessarily play well together. Since you are already using jquery, why not use it for the other fields too?

Comment: I want to say that DATALIST and jQuery's autocomplete are different and getting the way of getting the values of each of them is different.  I suggest making sure that the event that triggers auto fill of the various form elements is passing the correct value.

Comment: FYI: Removed `cfoutput` around the `cfquery` tags. Not needed, variables inside the query tag will be evaluated automatically.

Comment: @Leigh, so can I not have my inital input populated via AJAX and the rest of the inputs populated by a bind to a CFC? Is that a no no?

Comment: @BrianFleishman - I am not saying that *is* the issue, just that mixing two libraries can sometimes be problematic. Since you are already using jquery, why bother with cftextarea?

Comment: I'd still like to use my form elements as by entire page is built around them. Are you saying to use AJAX instead of the bind element to populate the related form inputs?

Comment: I am saying since both libraries can do that, why not just use one of them ie jQuery. Especially as the CF UI stuff is outdated. Like someone else put it on your other thread, the CF UI stuff is like training wheels. jQuery can grow to fit your needs. Since you are already using it, why not stick with it. Again, I am not saying this definitely *is* the cause your problem, but it is something to consider if you plan to use more ajax.

Comment: Yeah I agree. One of the reasons that I'm trying to switch over to Ajax instead of using the bind. So with that being said, I would just need a separate AJAX script to populate the rest of my inputs based on the value of the first input box?

Comment: Well it is all ajax. Just a matter of which library is used. You could do separate calls if you want. Another option is to return the other customer fields in the initial structure. Then populate the form fields inside `select: {...}` ie `$('#other_field').val(ui.item.otherKeyName);`

Comment: Thanks. I'll post a new question if I have any difficulty with my AJAX only solution.